# How to generate HTTP Request response data in JSON format?

Tags: jmeter, httpresponse

How to generate HTTP Request response data in JSON format? I am getting the response data in the HTML format.

In the HTTP Header Manager, I am sending the Content-Type = application/json. In the HTTP request body data I am sending the data in the JSON format.
What are the changes I should make to get the response in the JSON format?

I want to extract some values from the JSON response and use in the script.

Comment: It depends on application/server definition, if it doesn't support JSON it won't return JSON format

Comment: My application support JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your HTTP endpoint specification and requirements. The reasons of getting response can be different, we cannot help without seeing the endpoint details, request and response data.

Among the possible reasons are:

- Incorrect [HTTP Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) used. In this case you can get [HTTP 406 response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406)
- Invalid [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL). In this case you can get [HTTP 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) response
- Invalid request headers. I.e. missing [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) or [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) headers. You can add arbitrary headers using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)
- You're not authorized (missing cookie or token). In this case you can get HTTP [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) or [403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) statuses

Comment: The issue I am facing is with the script which I recorded with Blazemeter  Chrome plugin. When I use the same API in a manually created JMeter script I am getting the response data in the json format.

Comment: I believe you should address this form of questions to [BlazeMeter Support](https://www.blazemeter.com/support)